# Delay in drawing an element with mouse click if user input is requested in open cv python

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I wanted to draw points with labels at mouse click on an image. In the following code it draws blue points for first 3 left mouse clicks, thereafter red points. It works fine so far. However, if I enable the user input requesting part marked by `<---` it doesn't show the 3rd blue point until I give the user input. What I was expecting was the user input request comes after it draws the 3rd blue point. Any help is appreciated. Thanks !!

Here's the code. Please comment out `<---` marked line #26 which calls for the user input and it works fine.

```
import cv2

img_path = r'test.jpg'

count = 0
red_count = 0
user_inp = None


def click_event(event, x, y, flags, params):
    global count, red_count, user_inp

    font_scale, point_radius = 0.4, 2
    font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX

    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:

        if count < 3:
            text = f"blue{count}"
            cv2.putText(img, text, (x + 2, y), font, font_scale, (255, 0, 0), 1)
            cv2.circle(img, (x, y), radius=point_radius, color=(255, 0, 0), thickness=-1)
            cv2.imshow('image', img)

            if count == 2:
                print("blue index 2")
                user_inp = input('input anything: ')  # <------------ check here

        if count >= 3:
            text = f"red{red_count}"
            cv2.putText(img, text, (x + 2, y), font, font_scale, (0, 0, 255), 1)
            cv2.circle(img, (x, y), radius=point_radius, color=(0, 0, 255), thickness=-1)
            cv2.imshow('image', img)
            red_count += 1

        count += 1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    img = cv2.imread(img_path, 1)
    cv2.imshow('image', img)

    cv2.setMouseCallback('image', click_event)

    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    print(user_inp)
```

Comment: that's a callback. you can't spend arbitrary time in a callback, certainly you shouldn't block and wait for a line of user input in a callback. -- you need a proper GUI, and GUI toolkit. openCV's facilities are convenient, not flexible. all the usual GUI libraries have a certain lifecycle, i.e. the GUI is in control, and you only get to run your code in callbacks, or in spawned threads. -- brace yourself, you might require a kind of "state machine", where different steps are decoupled from each other, and only get triggered by events from the GUI.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I will try using Kivy or Tkinter.